# Unable to open gpkg files

Tags: r, sf, geopackage

I am trying to load several gpkg files into R but got some problems.
Initially this code works:

```
library("dplyr")
library("rgdal")
library("sp")
library("st")
library("sf")

setwd("C:\Users\filename.gpkg")
temp = list.files(pattern=".gpkg")
myfiles = lapply(temp, st_read)
```

Also, this works for each file (but I have more than 15 files):

```
st_read("filename.gpkg", layer= 'layerx')
```

But I need to specify the layer, so I code this way:

```
temp = list.files(pattern=".gpkg", full.names= TRUE)
tem2 = lapply(temp, st_read(dsn= '.',layer= 'layerx'))
```

But does not work, produce this error:

```
Error: Cannot open "C:\Users\"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lapply`, the second argument needs to be a function definition (not a function call).

Please try replacing the last expression with:

```r
tem2 = lapply(temp, function(x) st_read(x, layer= 'layerx'))
```

Comment: Great Michael, that worked!!

Comment: It would be polite to upvote and accept the answer then.